# oracle update sql using python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I tried to make some DML cases in oracle using python Cx_Oracle.
These are cases:

```
#####DML TEST CASE###########

case1 = """
INSERT INTO Table(code, detailcode, VALUE1, VALUE2)
values('1111','1','2','3')
"""

case2 = """
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Table(code, detailcode, VALUE1, VALUE2)
values('1111','1','2','3');
INSERT INTO Table(code, detailcode, VALUE1, VALUE2)
values('2222','1','2','3');
INSERT INTO Table(code, detailcode, VALUE1, VALUE2)
values('3333','1','2','3');
COMMIT;
END;
"""

case3 = """
UPDATE Table SET value1='9999' WHERE code='1111'
"""

case4 = """
UPDATE Table SET value1='6666' WHERE code='2222'
"""

case5 = """
DELETE FROM Table WHERE code='3333'
"""

case0 = """
DELETE FROM Table
"""
```

after connected successfully, I also made a code to run DML.

```
def DML(sql):
    dsn = ora.makedsn('*',*,'*')
                    
    db = ora.connect('*','*',dsn)
    db.begin()
    cursor=db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

in this code, there was a problem that in case 3 and case 4, the commit() might not be sended.
Is there any way to send sql lines and send commit explicitly, or manually control the transactions in python Cx_Oracle?(I should not use auto commit)

Comment: Why wouldn't they be sent?  If there was a problem, then you don't WANT the transaction to be committed.

Comment: I know your simple example may be different from the statements you actually execute, but with the given names you should pass the data in case 1 & case 2 in a single [`executemany()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html) call.  And case 3 & case 4 should also be combined into a single `executemany()` call.  Unless you are doing two phase commits, you can remove the begin() and close() calls.

Answer (score 0):

The cx_Oracle cursor can process one SQL operation in time.
So the only way to add the "COMMIT" into SQL is to wrap it in PL/SQL block, as you did in case2.

for example, case 3 with integral commit:

```
case3 = """BEGIN

UPDATE Table SET value1='9999' WHERE code='1111' ;

COMMIT;

END;
"""
```